# Async/Await without await call

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a virtual method that sometimes contain await calls and sometimes doesn't. The IDE does give me warning, what is the proper way of handling this ?

In my base class:

```
protected virtual async Task GoNext ()
```

From the base class it get called via await.

Then in my sub-classes i override this method but there are times that it does include a await and times that it doesn't.

Comment: I don't understand the question. `async` is not part of the method signature that is inherited. Simply don't write `async` when declaring an overridden method that doesn't use `await`. You will still have to return a `Task` or `Task<T>` though. You should post some code that exhibits the problem as well as the actual warning, so that there is no confusion about which actual problem you're having.

Comment: Can't you ommit the async keyword if the method doesn't use the await keyword?

Comment: some examples of what you found, should make it a better question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `async` keyword is not actually part of the inherited method signature, but more of a signal to the compiler that it needs to compile and rewrite the method according to the pattern for async methods.

As such, you can leave out the `async` keyword on inherited methods if the inherited method does not use the `await` keyword.

Note that you will still have to return a `Task` or `Task<T>`, that part *is* part of the inherited method signature.

So this will give you a warning:

```
class Base
{
    public virtual async Task<int> Method()
    {
        await Task.Delay(10);
        return 42;
    }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    // next line produces warning
    public override async Task<int> Method()
    {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

The warning is this:

> Warning: CS1998 This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the `await` operator to await  non-blocking API calls, or `await Task.Run(...)` to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

This, however, will not produce a warning:

```
class Derived : Base
{
    public override Task<int> Method()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(42);
    }
}
```

Note that I changed the `return` statement in that last method because part of the "magic" that the `async` keyword brings is to automatically wrap the return value inside a `Task<T>`. If you have other ways of obtaining a `Task<T>`, obviously you do not need to wrap the result like I did above.